# C++ unit testing using a scripting language

Tags: c++, ruby, perl, unit-testing, scripting

I would like to utilize some scripting language in order to perform unit testing of the C++ code. It could be easier to develop tests in a scripting language given that it has access to the required C++ functions.

I have either Ruby or Perl in mind (because I am familiar with them). It seems that I could use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to interface with the C++ code.

Are there any better alternatives to [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)? What scripting language would you personally use for this purpose?

And finally, is it appropriate (and efficient) to use this approach to testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Inline:CPP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aCPP) provides a relatively simple means of calling C++ code from Perl.

I recommend running your script using the following (or with an equivalent directive inside of the test script):

```
perl -MInline=FORCE,NOISY,NOCLEAN test.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your C++ code in a similar manner to how you would test Perl code, you could use a library designed to output [TAP](http://testanything.org).

Looking at the [page listing the TAP producers](http://testanything.org/wiki/index.php/TAP_Producers#C_.2F_C.2B.2B) There appears to be [only one designed specifically for C++](http://testanything.org/wiki/index.php/Testing_with_C++#Testing_using_libtap.2B.2B).

You may also want to look at the [GitHub page for libtap++](https://github.com/Leont/libperl--/blob/master/tap++/doc/libtap++.pod).

```
#include <tap++.h>
#include <string>

using namespace TAP;

int foo() {
  return 1;
}

std::string bar() {
  return "a string";
}

int main() {
  plan(3);
  ok(true, "This test passes");
  is(foo(), 1, "foo() should be 1");
  is(bar(), "a string", "bar() should be \"a string\"");
  return exit_status();
}
```

Which produces something like:

```
1..3
ok 1 - This test passes
ok 2 - foo() should be 1
ok 3 - bar() should be "a string"
```

Which can be parsed by [prove](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/bin/prove) provided by [Test::Harness](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/).

---

The best part is you shouldn't have to learn a language other than the one you are already using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is an interesting approach, but I think that only using libtap++ will not suffice in my case. The main reason why I wanted to write all my tests in a scripting language is the ease of coding, flexibility, good string parsing (to verify output) and speed of development.  
However, I checked [libPerl++](https://github.com/Leont/libperl--) from the link you provided, and it seems like a neat library to interface with Perl API.

Comment: @ravil, you could use Perl to generate the C++ test programs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing C code and compiling it with the C++ compiler, using another language for testing can work.

But not for code written in a C++ style.

How do you test for correct and leak-free copy-construction, assignment, overloaded operators?  What about templates?  No scripting language is going to call these in the same way C++ does, many don't even have a concept of pass-by-value.

Test from the environment you're going to ultimately use to consume the code.

Comment: Thanks for you insight. Yes, I guess, it wouldn't be possible to perform in-depth unit testings using just scripting languages. What about functional/component testing?

Comment: @ravil: It depends on the interface.  If your interface consists of calling global functions with C-like signatures, you can do that from any language (after generating the appropriate bindings).  If your interface includes creation and destruction of class instances by the consumer, you may still be able to wrap the interface, but there's going to be a lot of work involved because the automatic wrapper generators fall short.

Comment: Actually, I believe ChaiScript will let you test your C++ code as if it were C++ code performing the testing. Every function call in ChaiScript is directly mapped to a C++ function call. The main difference being that ChaiScript is not a stack based language. All objects are created on the heap and the stack is emulated to match what you would expect in C++.